# On ubuntu:20.04, running apt install python3-pip broke, is there a fix?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt

Inside a docker image

```
public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:20.04
```

Running the command

```
apt install python3-pip
```

Stopped working. It breaks now. I tried this inside a basic ec2, and also using codebuilder. I don't know how report this. Is anyone else having this issue? What is the issue and is there a way to fix this?

It worked yesterday, but for some reason it stopped working today. I tried googling the issue but nothing seems to be coming up. It seems as though the ubuntu archives were updated today/yesterday, I'm guessing that broke it.

```
/# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential ca-certificates cpp cpp-9 dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot file g++ g++-9 gcc gcc-9 gcc-9-base gnupg
  gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5
  libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libexpat1-dev
  libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-9-dev libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libgomp1 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libisl22 libitm1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblocale-gettext-perl liblsan0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpc3 libmpdec2
  libmpfr6 libnpth0 libperl5.30 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libquadmath0 libreadline8
  libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libwind0-heimdal linux-libc-dev make
  manpages manpages-dev mime-support netbase openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.30 pinentry-curses python-pip-whl python3 python3-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
  python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal readline-common xz-utils zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-9-locales dbus-user-session libpam-systemd pinentry-gnome3 tor debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-9-multilib gcc-9-doc gcc-multilib autoconf
  automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-9-multilib parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon glibc-doc locales git bzr gdbm-l10n libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql libstdc++-9-doc make-doc man-browser ed diffutils-doc perl-doc
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl libb-debug-perl liblocale-codes-perl pinentry-doc python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python-setuptools-doc
  python3.8-venv python3.8-doc binfmt-support readline-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential ca-certificates cpp cpp-9 dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot file g++ g++-9 gcc gcc-9 gcc-9-base gnupg
  gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5
  libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-9-dev libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libgomp1 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libisl22 libitm1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblocale-gettext-perl liblsan0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpc3 libmpdec2
  libmpfr6 libnpth0 libperl5.30 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libquadmath0 libreadline8
  libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libwind0-heimdal linux-libc-dev make
  manpages manpages-dev mime-support netbase openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.30 pinentry-curses python-pip-whl python3 python3-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
  python3-minimal python3-pip python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal readline-common xz-utils zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6
1 upgraded, 113 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 75.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 319 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 [2714 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 liblocale-gettext-perl amd64 1.07-4 [17.1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10 [1322 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [717 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2 [74.7 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8-minimal amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [1900 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-minimal amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [23.6 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 mime-support all 3.64ubuntu1 [30.6 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmpdec2 amd64 2.4.2-3 [81.1 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 readline-common all 8.0-4 [53.5 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libreadline8 amd64 8.0-4 [131 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 [549 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-stdlib amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [1675 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8 amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [387 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpython3-stdlib amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [7068 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3 amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [47.6 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 perl-modules-5.30 all 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2 [2738 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgdbm6 amd64 1.18.1-5 [27.4 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgdbm-compat4 amd64 1.18.1-5 [6244 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libperl5.30 amd64 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2 [3952 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 perl amd64 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2 [224 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10 [620 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20210119~20.04.2 [145 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmagic-mgc amd64 1:5.38-4 [218 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmagic1 amd64 1:5.38-4 [75.9 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 file amd64 1:5.38-4 [23.3 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 netbase all 6.1 [13.1 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-pkg-resources all 45.2.0-1 [130 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 xz-utils amd64 5.2.4-1ubuntu1 [82.5 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 manpages all 5.05-1 [1314 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [207 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [474 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf-nobfd0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [47.4 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libctf0 amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [46.6 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [1613 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 binutils amd64 2.34-6ubuntu1.3 [3380 B]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 [71.6 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-100.113 [1120 kB]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libcrypt-dev amd64 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4 [104 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.7 [2518 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9-base amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [19.1 kB]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libisl22 amd64 0.22.1-1 [592 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmpfr6 amd64 4.0.2-1 [240 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmpc3 amd64 1.1.0-1 [40.8 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cpp-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [7494 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 cpp amd64 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 [27.6 kB]
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcc1-0 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [48.8 kB]
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [102 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libitm1 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [26.2 kB]
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libatomic1 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [9284 B]
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libasan5 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [394 kB]
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 liblsan0 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [835 kB]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libtsan0 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [2009 kB]
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libubsan1 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [784 kB]
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libquadmath0 amd64 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 [146 kB]
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgcc-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [2360 kB]
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [8241 kB]
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gcc amd64 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 [5208 B]
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libstdc++-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [1714 kB]
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 g++-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 [8405 kB]
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 [1604 B]
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 make amd64 4.2.1-1.2 [162 kB]
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libdpkg-perl all 1.19.7ubuntu3 [230 kB]
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 patch amd64 2.7.6-6 [105 kB]
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dpkg-dev all 1.19.7ubuntu3 [679 kB]
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 build-essential amd64 12.8ubuntu1.1 [4664 B]
Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libassuan0 amd64 2.5.3-7ubuntu2 [35.7 kB]
Get:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpgconf amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [124 kB]
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libksba8 amd64 1.3.5-2 [92.6 kB]
Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libroken18-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [41.8 kB]
Get:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [181 kB]
Get:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimbase1-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [29.7 kB]
Get:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhcrypto4-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [87.9 kB]
Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libwind0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [48.0 kB]
Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhx509-5-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [107 kB]
Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libkrb5-26-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [208 kB]
Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimntlm0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [15.1 kB]
Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgssapi3-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [96.1 kB]
Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [14.7 kB]
Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [49.3 kB]
Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [16.6 kB]
Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [155 kB]
Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libnpth0 amd64 1.6-1 [7736 B]
Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 dirmngr amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [329 kB]
Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libfakeroot amd64 1.24-1 [25.7 kB]
Get:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 fakeroot amd64 1.24-1 [62.6 kB]
Get:87 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gnupg-l10n all 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [51.7 kB]
Get:88 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gnupg-utils amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [480 kB]
Get:89 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpg amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [483 kB]
Get:90 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 pinentry-curses amd64 1.1.0-3build1 [36.3 kB]
Get:91 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpg-agent amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [232 kB]
Get:92 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpg-wks-client amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [97.6 kB]
Get:93 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpg-wks-server amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [90.3 kB]
Get:94 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gpgsm amd64 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [217 kB]
Get:95 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gnupg all 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1 [259 kB]
Get:96 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.03-2 [46.6 kB]
Get:97 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-6 [11.3 kB]
Get:98 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-3 [12.0 kB]
Get:99 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.2.9-1ubuntu0.2 [116 kB]
Get:100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libfile-fcntllock-perl amd64 0.22-3build4 [33.1 kB]
Get:101 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8 amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [1625 kB]
Get:102 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpython3.8-dev amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [3950 kB]
Get:103 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpython3-dev amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [7236 B]
Get:104 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [48.8 kB]
Get:105 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 manpages-dev all 5.05-1 [2266 kB]
Get:106 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 python-pip-whl all 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6 [1805 kB]
Get:107 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 [155 kB]
Get:108 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3.8-dev amd64 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.2 [510 kB]
Get:109 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-lib2to3 all 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 [76.3 kB]
Get:110 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-distutils all 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04 [141 kB]
Get:111 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-dev amd64 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 [1212 B]
Get:112 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 45.2.0-1 [330 kB]
Get:113 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 python3-wheel all 0.34.2-1 [23.8 kB]
Get:114 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 python3-pip all 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6 [231 kB]
Fetched 75.2 MB in 21s (3603 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 4127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.7_amd64.deb ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /                                                                                                                                                 usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/li                                                                                                                                                 b/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
ERROR: Your kernel version indicates a revision number
of 255 or greater.  Glibc has a number of built in
assumptions that this revision number is less than 255.
If you\'ve built your own kernel, please make sure that any
custom version numbers are appended to the upstream
kernel number with a dash or some other delimiter.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.7_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As per a comment that told me to run uname -a, here is the output

```
Linux 5a32863f8b3f 4.14.256-197.484.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 30 00:17:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with python or pip, as it happens during libc upgrade.

Comment: You might want to add the output of `uname -a` to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what is a libc, I guess its the ubuntu archive upgrade thing? I only know I cannot install python3-pip anymore. Also I do not know what is uname -a so I have no idea where to put it...

Comment: I just ran uname -a this is the output. Linux 5a32863f8b3f 4.14.256-197.484.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 30 00:17:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You might want to report this to AWS.

Comment: Are you saying the issue is unique to AWS's ubuntu:20.04 base image? So it is not happening on regular unbuntu/linux builds?

Comment: I'm saying that AWS uses a custom kernel and since this is about the kernel version number, this might be on them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that. It seems as though python3-pip install still works on regular linux ubuntu installs.

Comment: Maybe this one - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1962606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much rpi_guru. Apparently this issue has been reported at
[EDIT: For some reason stackoverflow is throwing an error with the links]

```
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1962606
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1962225
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=987266
```

With a workaround found in those forums.

1. Create a file "uname" with the contents of

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "-r" ]] ;then
    echo '4.9.250'
    exit
else
    uname.orig "$@"
fi
```

2. rename the original uname to uname.orig

```
mv /bin/uname /bin/uname.orig
```

3. install your uname script to bin with execute privileges

```
install -m 0755 /tmp/bin/uname /bin
```

Or you can add it into your Dockerfile with (taken from one of the buglinks)

```
COPY . /tmp/
RUN mv /bin/uname /bin/uname.orig \
    && install -m 0755 /tmp/uname /bin
```

Comment: Seems to be fixed so this workaround is no longer needed, but if anything else happens that may need this sort of workaround in the future for the same or different reason this can still be useful i think.